# Program not displaying anything

Tags: c

Whenever I attempt to run this code it will compile fine, but there is no display in the console. It should be printing out all the numbers in the linked list, I don't understand what the issue is.

**Header File**

```
#define RAND_MAX 100

struct num_node{
    int num;
    struct num_node* next;
};


struct num_node *create(struct num_node *list, int num);
void print_nums(struct num_node *list);
```

**Function source**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "functions.h"

struct num_node *create(struct num_node *list, int x){
    struct num_node *current;

    if (list == NULL){
        list = (struct num_node*)malloc(sizeof(struct num_node));
        list->num = x;
        list->next = NULL;
        return(list);
    }
    else{
        current = (struct num_node *)malloc(sizeof(struct num_node));
        current->num = x;
        current->next = list;
        return(current);
    }
} 

void print_nums(struct num_node *list) {

    struct num_node *current;
    for (current = list; current != NULL; current = current->next)
        printf("%d\n", current->num);

}
```

**Main**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#include "functions.h"

int main(){
    struct num_node *head = NULL;

    srand(time(NULL));

        for (int i = 1; i <= 25; i++){
            int x = rand() % 100;
            create(head, x);
        }

        print_nums(head);

}
```

Comment: A few minutes in a debugger would have avoided the need for this question altogether.

Answer (score 3):

You never use the value returned by `create`.

So `head` is still `NULL` when you pass it to `print_nums`.

It should be:  `head = create(head, x);`